# EF Core DbContext Transaction Shared Between API Services

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, transactions

Maybe I just need someone to confirm with me that I am good with this (because it appears to be working,) or point out something I am missing.

I have my example code for this question up on GitHub: https://github.com/tgourley/EFCoreTransactionTest

I have set up an ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 6) application to have two injected services (`CourseService` and `StudentService`) that will help create a course, create a student, add and remove a student from a course.  I'm using EF Core to handle saving data to the database.

When adding a student to a course, there are several things that are done: connect the student to the course, update the course's student count, and update the student's course count.

The `StudentService` is injected into the `CourseService`.  So for updates specific to the student, the `CourseService` calls into the `StudentService`.  For updates to the specific course entity, that just happens directly against the `DbContext`.

In the event that an error happens mid-update (simulated by just throwing an exception in the middle of the code,) I want whatever has been changed to roll back.  I have used the `BeginTransaction` function in the `DbContext` to use a transaction to contain all the changes.  My concern is that the `DbContext` that is injected into the `StudentService` might not operate under the same transaction as the `CourseService`.

```
public void AddStudentToCourseAtomic(int courseId, int studentId)
{
    using (var transaction = _dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var student = _studentService.GetStudentById(studentId);
            var course = GetCourseById(courseId);
            course.Students.Add(student);
            _studentService.UpdateStudentCourseCount(studentId, student.CurrentCourseCount + 1);
            student = _studentService.GetStudentById(studentId);
            throw new Exception("Problem adding student!");
            course.CurrentStudentCount++;
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So far, my testing seems to indicate that the changes in the `StudentService` are being rolled back when an error happens in this `CourseService` method.

Am I doing this correctly?  Anything else I need to keep in mind when doing this?

Comment: if the lifetime of your DBContext is Scoped, you can be safe and remove all the transaction-related code that you have... EF already implements a unit of work that will commit all changes as a transaction... If your dbContext is transient, you might need to create your own unit of work... Don't mix transactions with EF

Comment: @Berseker117 The DbContext is Scoped (using the basic service registration) but I am finding that the code noted in the question without being wrapped in a transaction does result in a couple of separate transactions (I think I count 2 or 3 in the logs though the logs are hard to decipher.)  When the exception happens, some updates that I want to roll back are committed to the database.  The code above fixes that by wrapping it in a transaction, but I wasn't sure if this was the way to "officially" handle this.

Comment: Following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions
It looks that you are safe